# Download zip xml file XAMARIN

Tags: xamarin

I have a command that does the download of the file and saves it in the folder, now to get faster the dowload I want to make it download the zipped file, so the file decreases the size and the dowload will be faster, somebody knows some way for me do that ?

At the moment I use the following command to download

```
 XDocument rss = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load("http://pox.globo.com/rss/g1/mg/sul-de-minas/");
            var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var filename = Path.Combine(path, "rss.xml");
            rss.Save(filename);
```

Comment: does the zip file already exist on your server?

Comment: Does not exist yet

Comment: url downlod zip = http://pox.globo.com/rss/g1/mg/sul-de-minas/

Comment: Did you try directly downloading the file (without using XDocument) as suggested yesterday?  For such a small file the overhead of dynamically zipping, downloading, and unzipping is likely to make the situation worse.

Comment: It has to be zipped upfront on your server. Then download the zipped file, extract it and pass the local file destination to the load function.

Comment: Yes, I tried to take xdocument

Comment: Would an asynchronous download